# Prove that if $X$ is measurable, then there exists an arbitrarily large $M$ such that $\mathbb P(|X| = M) = 0$

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification

> Prove that if $X$ is measurable, then there exists an arbitrarily large $M$ such that $\mathbb P(|X| = M) = 0$.

Here, $\mathbb P$ is a probability measure. This comes from Rick Durrett's Probability theory. I was wondering if you could check my reasoning for the proof of the above:

Let $N$ be arbitrarily large integer. Then $[N, \infty)$ is uncountable. If, for all $a > N$, $\mathbb P (|X| = a) > 0$, then $\mathbb P(|X| \geq N) = \infty$ because the sum of uncountably many positive terms is infinity. But since $\mathbb P$ is a probability measure, this is impossible.

Comment: $\{ M | P[|X|=M] > 0 \}$ must be at most countable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k$ be a positive integer. There are only a finite number of $x$'s with $P(|X|=x)>\frac  1k$. (In fact at most $k$ of them. This implies that there are only countably many $x$'s with $P(|X|=x)>0$.  Since $(n,\infty)$ is uncountable it follows that there is at least one  value of $x>N$ such that $P(|X|=x)=0$.

Comment: Your summation doesn't say what you are indexing $n$ over,  if it's the normal sum that's countable.  If not, it might be infinite if you took enough sample points less than 1, etc.